# How to add a <select> tag to an HTML doc when a user clicks on <a href...> tag using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I am creating a page that lets the user select an item from a list, and provides a mechanism to add additional items from the same drop down menu.

My HTML code snippet is:

```
<tr>
    <td class="ventureadd">Size</td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" size="10" name="txtAddress1" />
        <select id="selSize">
            <option value="noselection">Select One</option>
            <option value="feet">Sq. Feet</option>
            <option value="meters">Sq. Meters</option>
            <option value="gunta">Gunta</option>
            <option value="yards">Sq. Yards</option>
            <option value="acre">Acres</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

and the JavaScript is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".addhousinglink").click(function(){
        $('#addhousing').append(
            $("<p>Here's a jQuery object</p>")
        );
        return true;
    });
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Clean up your code first... There is a preview when creating the post. Use it.

Comment: That JavaScript doesn’t seem to refer to any of the HTML you’ve posted — none of the class or id values are the same. Where’s the HTML your JavaScript is trying to manipulate?

Comment: Would help if the jQuery is in relation to the HTML you provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options for such tasks, one - append, second - unhide. For complex non-dynamic stuff, I would suggest using second one.

Append (HTML)

```
<a id="thisIsAnchor" href="#">Add some dropdown box here!</a><div id="here"></div>
```

Append (JS)

```
$('#thisIsAnchor').click(function(){
    $('#here').append('<select><option>Here comes and option!</option><option>Then, what am I?</option></select>');
});
```

Unhide (HTML)

```
<a id="thisIsAnchor" href="#">Add some dropdown box here!</a><div id="here"><select style="display: none"><option>Here comes and option!</option><option>Then, what am I?</option></select></div>
```

Unhide (JS)

```
$('#thisIsAnchor').click(function(){
    $('#here select').show();
});
```

Comment: Because, you misspelled: append($("<p>Here's a jQuery object</p>")); correct it to append("<p>Here's a jQuery object</p>");

Comment: make sure, you have anchor with class "addhousinglink" and container with id "addhousing".

Answer (score 0):

Hey you can do this simply with the help of `html()` function in the jQuery. Here is how you cand do this --

First HTML --

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <a href="#test" id="test" >Click Me!</a>
    <div id="test_handler"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And her is the jQuery --

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a#test").click(function() {
        $("div#test_handler").html("<select name=\"test_select\"><option value=\"test\">Test</option></select>");
    });
});
```

Or you can view this link [jSfiddle#VmAuC](http://jsfiddle.net/VmAuC/1/)

This jSfiddle is with fading toggle effect --- http://jsfiddle.net/VmAuC/5/
(Hope you like this toggling effect!)

Tell if this helps you or if you want anything more you comment and ask me anytime.

Hope this helps!